How to test Revenue Cat purchases for App Store
I have Flutter app targeting iOS and Android. App has subscriptions and I am using Revenue Cat for this.
Android version works beautifully, but iOS is getting rejected by Apple App Store with dreaded Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed. They also mention:

Note that in-app purchases are reviewed in an Apple-provided sandbox environment. Make sure they have been appropriately configured for review in the Apple-provided sandbox environment.

To test subscriptions on iOS I used this Revenue Cat guide. I have created the StoreKit configuration as per the guide, and that works fine on my simulator. However, this is a special configuration that will only work for me. It uses a locally configured products and my public certificate. This is obviously not going to work for the Apple testers. Am I expected to send them my StoreKit configuration?
How can I test this using the same method Apple testers are going to use? If they are able to test this in their sandbox without using StoreKit, why do we even need the "StoreKit configuration" method, why not just test like Apple testers do?
I am fundamentally confused! Anyone understands how is this supposed to work?

You don't need to provide a store kit configuration file. Your in app purchases should also be in "submitted for review" state in App Store Connect.

My question is really about how to achieve this: "Make sure they [in-app purchases] have been appropriately configured for review in the Apple-provided sandbox environment." StoreKit is not it, so what is?

As long as your products are submitted for review in AppStore Connect they will work in the review sandbox.
